# python recursive algorithm multiprocess

Tags: python, recursion, python-multiprocessing

i'm trying to code a multi-process recursive algorithm in python 2.7, using a pool of workers and a manager to share a queue among processes.

Striping out all the algorithmic details the code looks like the following one:

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def pulse(l, c, accOut, v):
    print l, c, v
    if c < 3:
        c = c + 1
        l.append((v,c))
        pulse(l, c, accOut, v)
    else:        
        accOut.put(l)
        return

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    pool = Pool(processes=1)
    manager = Manager()
    accOut = manager.Queue()
    lNodes = manager.list(range(1, 7))
    partialCall = partial(pulse, list(), 0, accOut)
    pool.map(partialCall, lNodes)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "--- Lists in the queue: "
    while not accOut.empty():
        print accOut.get()
```

I am using only one worker in the pool for the sakeof simplicity. It is just the same with more workers but messier.
I expected an output like this one:

```
[] 0 1
[(1, 1)] 1 1
[(1, 1), (1, 2)] 2 1
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)] 3 1
[] 0 2
[(2, 1)] 1 2
[(2, 1), (2, 2)] 2 2
[(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)] 3 2
[] 0 3
[(3, 1)] 1 3
[(3, 1), (3, 2)] 2 3
[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)] 3 3
[] 0 4
[(4, 1)] 1 4
[(4, 1), (4, 2)] 2 4
[(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)] 3 4
[] 0 5
[(5, 1)] 1 5
[(5, 1), (5, 2)] 2 5
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)] 3 5
[] 0 6
[(6, 1)] 1 6
[(6, 1), (6, 2)] 2 6
[(6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3)] 3 6
--- Lists in the queue:
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
[(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
[(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)]
[(6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3)]
```

Instead I get something like this:

```
[] 0 1
[(1, 1)] 1 1
[(1, 1), (1, 2)] 2 1
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)] 3 1
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)] 0 2
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1)] 1 2
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2)] 2 2
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)] 3 2
[] 0 3
[(3, 1)] 1 3
[(3, 1), (3, 2)] 2 3
[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)] 3 3
[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)] 0 4
[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 1)] 1 4
[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 1), (4, 2)] 2 4
[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)] 3 4
[] 0 5
[(5, 1)] 1 5
[(5, 1), (5, 2)] 2 5
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)] 3 5
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)] 0 6
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (6, 1)] 1 6
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (6, 1), (6, 2)] 2 6
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3)] 3 6
--- Lists in the queue:
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)]
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3)]
```

I do not understand. Why this output? What am I doing wrong? Why, when the pulse function is called with v = 2 does not take a new list as input? Should I pass the list in the partial function in a different way?

I can easily obtain the expected result resetting the list l in the fist call of the pulse function but I think that it is not clean and there must be another way to do that.

I'm working in windows 10 64bit and a cannot change the python version.
I have already looked for a solution online but I have not found anything.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code might be easier to reason about if you used speaking names for your variables instead of c, v and l.

Comment: Not sure if this has to be with http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/ but it may be something related. I would suggest passing `None` to the function and constructing a new list if `l is None` just to check.

Comment: @MKesper I agree. My conclussions: `l` stands for 'list', `c` for 'count' and `v` for 'value'.

Comment: yeah, but c,v,l have no actual meaning since the pulse function does not do anything useful. They are just placeholders. I do no think the code would have been much cleaner if I had used different names.
However you are right l is list, c is count and v is value.

Comment: @Adirio It may, but why? I'm passing a new list every time. It keeps the lists generated with v = 1, 3, 5 but it does not keep the lists generated with v = 2 and 4.

I can pass None and construct a new list, that is basically the same as resetting the list in the first call of the pulse. It works, ok but I do not understand why is not working in the original way.

Comment: @Adirio I know that list is a mutable type and if I had done something like this:
`outputList = list()`
`partialCall = partial(pulse, outputList , 0, accOut)`
Then OK the list will be modified multiple times but I'm creating a new list every time.

Answer (score 0):

Either multiprocessing or functools module is doing some kind of batching and sending the same mutable `list` instance to two separate calls ([link](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)). Deeper inspecting should be carried out to notify this beahaviour to the corresponding entity. Meanwhile, use `None` as the argument and generate the instance of the `list` in the first `pulse` iteration.

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def pulse(l, c, accOut, v):
    if l is None:
        l = []
    print l, c, v
    if c < 3:
        c = c + 1
        l.append((v,c))
        pulse(l, c, accOut, v)
    else:        
        accOut.put(l)
        return

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    pool = Pool(processes=1)
    manager = Manager()
    accOut = manager.Queue()
    lNodes = manager.list(range(1, 7))
    partialCall = partial(pulse, None, 0, accOut)
    pool.map(partialCall, lNodes)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "--- Lists in the queue: "
    while not accOut.empty():
        print accOut.get()
```

You may actually want to swap argument order to give default values to some of them:

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def pulse(accOut, v, l=None, c=0):
    if l is None:
        l = []
    print l, c, v
    if c < 3:
        c = c + 1
        l.append((v,c))
        pulse(accOut, v, l, c)
    else:        
        accOut.put(l)
        return

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    pool = Pool(processes=1)
    manager = Manager()
    accOut = manager.Queue()
    lNodes = manager.list(range(1, 7))
    partialCall = partial(pulse, accOut)
    pool.map(partialCall, lNodes)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "--- Lists in the queue: "
    while not accOut.empty():
        print accOut.get()
```